# How to create a tx queue with dpdk

Tags: dpdk

I wish to queue packets in my own queues in dpdk. To that end, I made a queue struct containing mbufs so that after the rx burst, packets go into the queue. And some different lcore managing TX dequeue would take the first packet in the list and tx_burst it.

It seemed to work fine at first, but when I tried bursting a ton of packets into the switch, it dropped almost everything. I then thought of using spinlocks to make sure the RX lcore wouldn't touch the queue while the TX one is bursting something, but yet again it doesn't quite work. I set up a bunch of counters not unlike those of the l2fwd app to see what gets dropped or not, and in the end I get more packets received than those dropped + sent.

Here's what my enqueue thing looks like :

```
void
enqueue_update(struct rte_mbuf *m, unsigned portid)
{
        int i, j;
        uint64_t l;
        int lock_result;

        lock_result = rte_spinlock_trylock(&queue[portid].lock);
        if (lock_result == 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < sw_port_params[portid].qsize; i++) {
                        if ((queue[portid].mbufs[i]) == NULL) { 
                                queue[portid].mbufs[i] = m;
                                cnt.enq_check++;
                                rte_spinlock_unlock(queue[portid].lock);
                                return;            
                        }
                }
                rte_spinlock_unlock(queue[portid].lock);
                rte_pktmbuf_free(m);
                cnt.bad_tx_buff += 1;
                return; 
        }
}
```

The dequeueing thing :

```
void
dequeue_update(uint16_t n_tx_pkts, unsigned portid)
{
        int i, j, k;
        int lock_result = 1;
        uint16_t arrLen;

        struct rte_mbuf *tx_pkts[MAX_TX_PKT_BURST];
        uint16_t nb_tx;

        lock_result = rte_spinlock_trylock(&queue[portid].lock);
        if (lock_result == 1) {
                if ((queue[portid].mbufs[0]) == NULL) {
                        rte_spinlock_unlock(&queue[portid].lock);
                        return;
                }    
                tx_pkts[0] = queue[portid].mbufs[0];
                (queue[portid].mbufs[j]) = NULL;
                // rte_spinlock_unlock(&queue[portid].lock);
                // shift everything on the right of the packet towards it
                queue_shift(0, portid, "left");
                rte_spinlock_unlock(&queue[portid].lock);
                shaper(portid);
                nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, 0, tx_pkts, 1);
                if (nb_tx) {
                        port_statistics[portid].tx += 1;
                        // printf("out\n");
                }
        }
}
```

In which the shaper basically just waits a little to avoid back to back packets and queue_shift moves elements in the queue array to the left as seen below :

```
void queue_shift(int index, unsigned portid, char *direction)
{
        int lock_result = 1;
        int i;
        uint16_t arrCnt, arrLen;

        // lock_result = rte_spinlock_trylock(&queue[portid].lock);

        arrLen = sizeof queue[portid].mbufs / sizeof queue[portid].mbufs[0];
        for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
                if ((queue[portid].mbufs[i]) != NULL)
                        arrCnt++;
        }

        if (lock_result == 1) {
                if (strcmp(direction, "right") == 0) {
                        if (arrLen == sw_port_params[portid].qsize) {
                                rte_pktmbuf_free(queue[portid].mbufs[arrLen - 1]);
                                (queue[portid].mbufs[arrLen - 1]) = NULL; // maybe unnecessary
                                cnt.bad_tx_buff += 1;
                        }

                        for (i = sw_port_params[portid].qsize - 1; i > index + 1; i--) { // should be correct
                                queue[portid].mbufs[i] = queue[portid].mbufs[i - 1];
                        }   
                }
                if (strcmp(direction, "left") == 0) {
                        for (i = index; i < arrCnt; i++) {
                                queue[portid].mbufs[i] = queue[portid].mbufs[i + 1];
                        }
                        rte_pktmbuf_free(queue[portid].mbufs[arrCnt]);
                        queue[portid].mbufs[arrCnt] = NULL; // This line right here
                }
                // rte_spinlock_unlock(&queue[portid].lock); // is this correct ?
        }
}
```

Anyway, I can confirm that before adding all the spinlocks, I at least had coherent results with normal traffic, but with this, even if I sent 20 pkts on the same port at once, I get weird results like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BXRY.png)
So, if at all possible, I'd like to know what I'm missing and or misunderstanding. For example, if I comment the line with the "this line right here" in queue_shift, the switch then proceeds to send  the last packet over and over again for seemingly no reason. I am at a total loss here...

Answer (score 0):

I did kinda solve the issue.

If that helps, I decided to try using rwlocks instead of spinlocks, and it seemed to do the trick. Also, I ended up avoiding trylocks altogether. I seems like spinlocks are less permissive than rwlocks.
I still do not know why some packets got duplicated indefinitely, but I managed to fix it by trial and error.